# Chrome crashes when opened with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I am launching Chrome browser from python shell using Selenium webdriver, it works well and good. But, when I launch the browser using the same code from inside a Python script, it crashes. How can I solve it?

Comment: plz provide code

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome()`

It crashes just about 2 seconds after opening.

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it.
The reason was that I was not providing a url after opening the broswer.

We need to provide the url after opening the browser so that it can go to a specific page and it works fine, else it will crash.

Comment: even there is no URL, empty browser has to be display. it will not crash.

Comment: @muraliselenium Yes, but it does crash with an empty browser. What should be done to avoid that?